# CROSS compilation of BTRFS file system

Tags: compiling, btrfs

We are developing Beaglebone black based custom board,
We are planing to use eMMC for storage.
To decide the file system on the eMMC we want to cross compile Btrfs user space utility,
Does anyone know the steps to cross compile btrfs user space utility for ARM based board ?

If yes please share it with me, I googled but failed to find the cross compilation steps.

I am getting following error while cross compiling,

```
btrfs-convert.c:42:28: fatal error: ext2fs/ext2_fs.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ext2fs/ext2_fs.h>
                            ^
```

Any suggestions pointers?

Answer (score 1):

`ext2fs.h` is provided by the [`e2fslibs-dev` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/e2fslibs-dev).
So perhaps check if you have e2fslibs-dev installed.

Comment: Thank you for reply Jaymin, i will check and update the result. `package link` says package is for `i386` and `amd64`. Do you know if its available for arm as well ?